# How can I modify the time I display with my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, datepicker

Please someone help me...

So I got this JS function which allows me to display the time:

```
function getCurrentTime() {

        var CurrentTime = "";

        try {
            var CurrentDate = new Date();
            var CurrentHours = CurrentDate.getHours();
            var CurrentMinutes = CurrentDate.getMinutes();
            var CurrentSeconds = CurrentDate.getSeconds();

            if (CurrentMinutes < 10) { CurrentMinutes = "0" + CurrentMinutes; }
            if (CurrentSeconds < 10) { CurrentSeconds = "0" + CurrentSeconds; }
            if (CurrentHours < 10) { CurrentHours = "0" + CurrentHours; }

            CurrentTime = "" + CurrentHours + ":" + CurrentMinutes + ":" + CurrentSeconds + "";
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
        return CurrentTime;
    }
```

And I return it along a jQuery datepicker like so:

```
$('.class').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: "dd.mm.yyyy" + " " + getCurrentTime(),
}
```

The problem that I have is that in the box in which I select the current date, I cannot modify the time, even if I change the numbers after the date is selected I always get the current time and instead I wish I could have whatever time I have introduced in the field.

Can you please help me for a way around this ?

Comment: For setting date you should use setDate    
 $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: Why don't you just store the time in a global variable, the re-use it?!

Comment: care to elaborate please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must modified picker property like this

```
 $('.class').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
        onSelect:function(date){

           $(this).val(date+" "+ getCurrentTime());
        }
  });
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using `new Date()`, which returns the current date and time.

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

If you want to modify the date and time, use the above mentioned methods to create a date/time of your choice.

Comment: but I wish it to return the current time by default, with the possibility to be modified into whatever time I wish afterwards.

Comment: You should make the `getCurrentTime` function, receive an argument. If there is no argument use `new Date()` & if there is an argument use `new Date(argument)` to generate the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

**You may probably looking for :**

```js
function curdate(){
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
return new Date(year, month, day, 00, 01);
}

    $('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'
    });
    $("#startdatetime-from").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(curdate());
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



<div id="startdatetime-from" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-input"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use datetimepicker, I have to work with the code that I presented to you.

Comment: You can't modify  time with .datepicker() for that you have to use .datetimepicker()

Comment: the time that I want to modify is in another function. I just display it in date picker via the format option.